# XamDataGrid XamTabControl WPF MVVM Peculiar Behavior

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, xamdatagrid

I'm facing a problem in implementing the following scenario:

When the user selects a record in a XamDataGrid, the control flows into another tab showing the details of the selected record.

The way I have done this is:

At the selection change of the XamDataGrid, I'm sending index of the tab to be activated using MVVM Light Messenger.

Setting the property bound to the Seledted Index of the Tab Control to that number.

Everything works smooth till here. Afetr that if I go back to the tab containing the grid, somehow the control comes back to tab which was activated.

As if, some intrinsic selection of cells in happening in the grid. Does Hover also affects the selection of the xamdatagrid?

I'm new  to Infragistics and kind of confused. If some one can help.

All code are in View Model files and no code in the code behind of xaml file.

Cheers,

Anshuman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around a lot. 
But the only way to get this wqorking was to disable all hover animations and effects.
Now it works as expected!